# Prove or disprove $\mathbb{P}( \lim_{n \to +\infty}{Y_n} \textrm{ exists in } \mathbb{R} ) =0 \textrm{ or } 1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, statistics, solution-verification

$\{X_n : n\geq 1\}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables where $\mathbb{E} [X_n]=0$ and $\mathbb{E} [X_n^2]=1$. Assume that $\{ a_n : n\geq 1\}$ is a sequence of non negative real numbers and $Y_n = \sum_j a_j \cdot X_j $.

Prove or disprove $\mathbb{P}( \lim_{n \to +\infty}{Y_n} \textrm{ exists in } \mathbb{R} ) =0 \textrm{ or } 1$

I appreciate it if you can tell me if the statement holds so that I can work on a proof or a counterexample.

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero%E2%80%93one_law

Comment: Thanks @Arthur for sharing, does that mean that the statement is True and we can prove it using Kolmogorov 0-1 law?

Comment: Yes all that you'd have to is show that limit that $Y_n$ exists is a tail event of $X_n$'s and then the rest is done by Kolmogorov.

Comment: Thank you @MilosTasic